# How to control RPI remotely using sim card connectivity

Tags: ethernet, server

I am setting up an IoT station, with a Raspberry Pi 3 and a mobile modem for the connectivity (Netgear LB1111) that work with a SIM card and it is connected to the RPI with an ethernet cable.

The main issue here is that I am not sure if I can get a fixed IP.

So how can I comunicate remotely with this RPI, to send real time command to the station?

Comment: I'm not sure if the Pi is relevant to this question.  Wouldn't any box have the same issue?

Comment: Yes, but maybe there is some ready to use RPI tools or library that I can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that most carriers implement a very strict NAT when it comes to mobile data. You will need to, at least, implement a reverse connection ***from the Pi*** to the controller, depending on your setup. See below.

**Depending on your setup**

- Whether your Pi asks for information (e.g. by polling a REST API) or
- Whether your Pi acts as a server for you to connect to

You may or may not need to do any special measures.

If your Pi follows the first bullet, you do not need to do anything, since most carriers allow outbound connections.

If your Pi is a server (second bullet), you will need to implement reverse connections (or reverse tunneling, depending on your setup), since most carriers DO NOT allow port forwarding (or *unrelated* inbound connections) with mobile data.

Keyword is **reverse tunneling**. Go do some research. Start your experiments with *reverse SSH*. If you can do that, you can do anything.